# Différence entre « rentrer » et « arriver »

Tags: sens, usage, vocabulaire

Je ne comprends pas la différence entre les verbes *rentrer* et *arriver*.
Par exemple, quelle est la différence entre

> Je suis rentré dans mon pays

et

> Je suis arrivé dans mon pays

Comment: Quel est le problème ? [renter](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/rentrer) vs [arriver](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/arriver)

Comment: @Unf: le Wiktionnaire est peut-être un peu plus lisible (et traduit). Et je ne trouve pas que la différence soit si évidente.

Comment: Notez également que, malgré les riches réponses ci-dessous, ils arrivent souvent qu'ils soient plus ou moins interchangeables, donc pas besoin de trop se prendre la tête je pense.

Comment: @JeromeJ, interchangeable, rarement, mais la nuance peut ne pas être importante dans certains contextes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Rentrer** : on arrive dans une zone qu'on connaît déjà

> Je rentre chez moi. / Je suis rentré en France.

Pour insister sur l'action :

> Bon je ne peux plus attendre, je rentre ! / Allez rentre, il fait froid dehors.

**Arriver** : notion de temps mise en avant

> Attends-moi, j'arrive. / J'arriverai vers 8 heures.

Fin d'un déplacement, d'un acte :

> Je suis arrivé à destination. / On y est arrivé, on a réussi !

Answer (score 6):

*Entrer* quelque part, c'est y pénétrer.

*Rentrer* quelque part, c'est y pénétrer quand on y avait déjà été présent, en particulier quand on y a des attaches fortes.

*Aller* quelque part, c'est se déplacer dans sa direction.

*Venir* quelque part, c'est se déplacer dans sa direction, avec un point de référence (souvent la position d'un des locuteurs) à la destination.

*Revenir* quelque part, c'est se déplacer dans sa direction alors qu'on s'en était éloigné, avec un point de référence (souvent la position d'un des locuteurs) à la destination.

*Retourner* quelque part, c'est quitter l'endroit où on est ou changer de direction pour aller vers ce lieu dont on était venu.

*Arriver* quelque part, c'est atteindre une destination (finale ou simplement une étape).