# Différence entre « rentrer », « retourner » et « revenir »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage

Quelle différence y a-t-il entre « rentrer », « retourner » et « revenir » ? Selon mon dictionnaire tous ces mots désignent la même chose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Différence entre « rentrer » et « arriver »](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/diff%c3%a9rence-entre-rentrer-et-arriver)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nous sommes en présence de trois verbes construits de la même façon :

- re-entrer
- re-tourner
- re-venir

dont certains sens peuvent se recouper (en particulier celui de « aller de nouveau »), mais ils ne sont jamais entièrement synonymes et sont chacun très larges d'emploi avec de nombreux emplois figurés.

Je dirais que ces trois verbes sont synonymes uniquement quand ils signifient « rentrer/retourner/revenir **chez soi** ».

**Rentrer**, c'est étymologiquement *entrer de nouveau*. Mais depuis longtemps (XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle) il est utilisé aussi comme synonyme de *entrer*, le préfixe *re* ayant perdu dans ce cas son sens de « encore une fois/de nouveau », et les deux verbes sont en concurrence pour signifier « pénétrer quelque part ».
Quelqu'un vient chez moi pour la première fois, je peux lui dire aussi bien :
« Je vous en prie, entrez » que « je vous en prie, rentrez ».

Alors que quand je dis « Je rentre chez moi » le préfixe *re* a gardé tout son sens de *retour au point de départ*.  Par contre dans ce cas « entrer » perd un peu de son sens de « pénétrer  quelque part » pour se rapprocher du sens de « aller » et peut signifier tout simplement : « je vais de nouveau chez moi  ».

Dans **retourner**, le préfixe *re*  conserve pleinement son sens de *de nouveau/retour au point de départ*, par contre c'est le verbe « tourner » qui a perdu sa valeur sémantique originale pour prendre le sens de « aller ».
On emploie souvent ce verbe comme synonyme de « renvoyer » (retourner un colis à son expéditeur, par exemple). Au sens figuré on peut « retourner un compliment ».

Dans **revenir**, le préfixe *re* et le verbe **venir** conservent tous les deux toute leur valeur sémantique, et « revenir » c'est bien « aller de nouveau à son point de départ » ou, dans ses nombreux sens figurés,  « retrouver son état initial ».

Answer (score 5):

Le sens que ces trois mots ont en commun est celui de se diriger une seconde fois vers un lieu. On pourra dire : *revenir* à la maison, *rentrer* à la maison ou *retourner* à la maison.

Cependant, **rentrer** contient la notion de se diriger vers un endroit duquel on est parti peu avant, une destination « finale », souvent une demeure où l'on habite... On *rentre* à la maison, mais on ne *rentre* pas au travail. Dire simplement *Je rentre* suffit à signifier qu'on rentre à la maison.

C'est à mon avis la seule différence stricte... Et je pense qu'il est plus naturel de dire *je rentre à la maison* que *je reviens à la maison* ou *je retourne à la maison* car on a l'habitude d'inclure cette idée de destination *finale* quand on parle. Dans les autres situations (destination *temporaire*) on pourra employer *revenir* ou *retourner*.

A noter les autres sens fréquents de **retourner**, qui signifie dans son sens premier: tourner dans un autre sens: *retourner la viande sur le feu*, ou *se retourner sur soi-même*; et de **rentrer**, qui a également le sens de faire entrer un objet dans un contenant, comme un emboîtement. Par exemple, *faire rentrer un tuyau dans un autre*, ou de manière figurée, *rentrer en soi-même*. Ou bien encore, *rentrer* dans un magasin, le magasin englobant la personne une fois celle-ci entrée dedans.

Answer (score 1):

Il y a une nuance cruciale entre *retourner* et *revenir* qui manque dans les réponses de Laure et de Maxim.

Pour *retourner* quelque part, on doit absolument être **ailleurs** que le lieu où on s'en va, et où l'on est déjà allé, alors que *revenir* implique que l'on part de là où l'on se trouve, mais qu'on y sera à nouveau dans un certain délai:

- *J'en reviens* signifie qu'on était parti du lieu où l'on est, mais qu'on y est maintenant de nouveau, ce qui complète notre voyage.
- *J'y retourne* signifie au contraire que l'on quitte le lieu où l'on se trouve pour aller ailleurs, et que le voyage sera complété à cet autre endroit, dont on ne **reviendra pas nécessairement**.

Dans les deux cas, il y a aller-et-retour, mais dans le cas de *retourner* on n'a pas encore fait la partie "retour", alors que dans *revenir*, le voyage entier est considéré d'un coup.

Comment: Beaucoup d'autres nuances sont absentes de ma réponse, que j'ai résumé par « sont chacun très larges d'emploi », ma réponse ne traitait que de *[verbe] chez soi*.  « Rentrer » ne rentre pas de le schéma de ta réponse et la question porte sur les 3 verbes. Si on aborde la question en introduisant les pronoms personnels, il ne faut pas oublier de traiter les différences non évidentes pour un non francophone *j'y reviens* vs *j'en reviens*, *j'y rentre* vs *j'en rentre*, pourquoi on ne peut pas dire *j'en retourne* mais on peut dire *il en retourne*, et d'autres...

Comment: C'est vrai, mais ça me semblait une différence particulièrement importante à mentionner car elle affecte directement le sens que ces verbes partagent, et c'est sans aborder les sens régionaux: *rentrer* s'emploie de manière très différente au Québec!

Comment: Un commentaire (ou une réponse) sur le sens de rentrer au Québec serait par contre intéressant. Voir  http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/q/560/358.La différence entre « aller » et « venir » que tu développes dans ta réponse était bien présente dans la mienne (je l'ai vu après relecture) ; j'ai signalé que « retourner » avait pris le sens de « aller ». Je n'avais pas développé, celui qui a posé la question doit à mon avis connaître la différence, il n'est pas débutant.

Comment: La différence majeure (*rentrer dans* avec le sens de *entrer en collision avec*) n'est pas pertinente. La seule autre variation important est que *rentrer au travail* est un usage très communs ici au sens de "retourner au travail à la suite d'un conflit syndical".

Answer (score 0):

Les réponses sont complètes mais je trouve cette petite histoire intuitive.

> Monsieur et Madame Lagrange passent leurs vacances à Singapour. Ils
> adorent visiter différents pays du monde, et ils ont eu un vrai coup
> de cœur pour cet endroit.
>
> Mais malheureusement, les vacances se
> finissent bientôt et ils vont devoir **rentrer** à la maison. Ils espèrent
> pouvoir **revenir** bientôt.
>
> Une fois arrivée en France, Madame Lagrange demande à son mari : «
> Alors, quand est-ce qu’on **retourne** à Singapour ? »

Source :

https://francais.lingolia.com/fr/vocabulaire/mots-confondus/autres/rentrer-revenir-retourner

Answer (score -1):

Il y’a une différence entre « revenir «  qui signifie être aller à et ne pas revenir «  être en revenir des rêves d’être aller au sport en revenir , signifie cautionner un voyage et ne pas le faire à la de DIRECT REVENIR de la proposition des gens de passages

Comment: Bienvenue sur FSE, mais il faudrait quand même écrire des réponses compréhensibles. Celle-ci n'a malheureusement ni queue ni tête.

Comment: C'est bien intriguant comme affirmation... à réviser.